# Jasig CAS LDAP - How to get roles

Tags: ldap, cas, jasig

I have jasig 3.4.7 installed with OpenLDAP and ssl enabled. I can login through CAS to an account created in the LDAP : fine.

Now I need to declare services via the management interface : I realized I've no "admin" account. So I tried to add a group "ADMIN" to my user. My first question : is it the right way ?

I've contextSource declared this way :

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.util.AuthenticatedLdapContextSource">
```

What do I need in order CAS to retrieve my user admin group. I tried :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
  <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
  <constructor-arg value="ou=Groups"/>
  <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn"/>
  <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(uniqueMember={0})" />
</bean>
```

But DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator is incompatible with jasig AuthenticatedLdapContextSource.

What bean should I use instead. I've seen some people dont use jasig context source but default spring org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource instead. Is it correct ? Would it help ?

Thanks,

Comment: I switched to 3.5.2 and used org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource instead of org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.util.AuthenticatedLdapContextSource wich is not anymore part of version 3.5.2.